# "for" loop not working in R when utilizing a package

Tags: r, for-loop

My question was edited because I believe I made things more confusing the way I wrote it.

I have various lists, each list is named with a color (yellow, red, green, etc). Each list contains a set of gene names. For example

```
yellow = c("CCR1", "CD14", "MTOR")
red = c("IL6", "CXCL8")
```

These genes can be queried in the enrichR package. For example, the code `yellow_enrich<- enrichr(yellow, databases = "KEGG_2019_Human")` queries the names inside the list "yellow" in the KEGG database, and it works fine.

```
> yellow_enrich <- enrichr(yellow, databases = "KEGG_2019_Human")
Uploading data to Enrichr... Done.
  Querying KEGG_2019_Human... Done.
Parsing results... Done.
> yellow_enrich
$KEGG_2019_Human
                                                    Term Overlap
1                             Osteoclast differentiation  17/127
2                        Staphylococcus aureus infection   14/68
3                                              Phagosome  16/152
4                                           Tuberculosis  15/179
```

Because I have many lists I tried to make a loop to query each color and store it in the environment.

```
for(i in uniquemods){assign(paste0(i,"_enrich"), enrichr(i, databases = "KEGG_2019_Human"))}
```

here, "uniquemods" is a list of all my colors. This code is supposed to give me objects named "color enrich" with the output of enrichR query. For example, `uniquemods = c("red", "yellow")`. The "yellow_enrich" that comes out from this loop looks like this:

```
$KEGG_2019_Human
[1] Term                 Overlap              P.value             
[4] Adjusted.P.value     Old.P.value          Old.Adjusted.P.value
[7] Odds.Ratio           Combined.Score       Genes               
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

So I am not sure why it is different. Maybe it is querying "yellow" instead of the names inside the list yellow? How do I fix this?

Comment: I seriously doubt that the code "works fine". You cannot have spaces in R object names without special effort. Perhaps try your loop construction with `paste0`

Comment: good point. although I will incorporate this in my code, it did not solve the issue. Now I'm thinking what is being queried in enrichr are the list names, not the lists. Actually, "enrichment <- enrichr(yellow, databases = "KEGG_2019_Human")" works fine. The objects created by the loop have spaces and they are created without issue besides not having the results of the query, regardless of using paste0 or paste.

Answer (score 0):

From the help page of `?enrichr` it says that it accepts a character vector and returns a list of dataframes. So something like this should work.

```
library(enrichR)
uniquemods <- c('yellow', 'green', 'red')

result <- lapply(mget(uniquemods), function(x) 
                 enrichr(x, databases = "KEGG_2019_Human")[[1]])
names(result) <- paste0(names(result), '_enrich')
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. However, sorry, I think I was not clear in my question. What is queried in enrichR are gene names (such as IL6, CXCL8, MTOR), not colors. In my case, red is a list that contains one set of genes, yellow would contain another set and so on.

Comment: @DiogodeMoraes: We would like to help, but if you keep replying in comments with statements that are not backed up with code examples, it's likely that we will continue to be taking past each other.

Comment: IRTFM and Ronak, I edited my question to make it more clear. Yes Ronak, it is exactly like that